# face recognition using eigen faces

Tags: matlab, face-recognition, eigenvector

i am new to programming so pardon me if doubt is silly..
this function was used in one of the program i was studying in matlab..
function [X y width height names] = read_images(path)..
i am little confused abt what path to be provided in the func read_image
code following this function is

```
folder = list_files(path);
    X = [];
    y = [];
    names = {};
    n = 1;
    for i=1:length(folder)
        subject = folder{i};
        images = list_files([path, filesep, subject]);
        if(length(images) == 0)
            continue;
        end
        added = 0;
        names{n} = subject;
        for j=1:length(images)
            filename = [path, filesep, subject, filesep, images{j}];
```

again what the "folder" means i mean what i have to provide there.plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
folder = list_files(path); % get all files from a given path
    images = list_files([path, filesep, subject]);
```

filesep seperate the 2 directories path and subject. two matrix is created 1st is path and 2nd is subject, ignore a file or empty folder.

Comment: what about this..what path is to be given in the parameter field?      function [X y width height names] = read_images(path)

Comment: Try to give the path where your images are saved, for example 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\'